# Most efficient way to ensure sequential commands in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

**Root Cause / Fix:**

Turns out this was an issue with the specific winston-papertrail lib I am using and that's why it wasn't behaving as expected, even using the `.finally()` block.

The `winston-papertrail` examples didn't use `end()` but found the proper syntax in the upstream Winston lib examples: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/73ae01f951600306242e00dd0d2b0a85b6d9d254/examples/finish-event.js#L28

### Once that was discovered, I was able to just add it to the `.finally()` block and everything worked fine **as defined in the accepted answer**

---

---

### Original Post:

> This is specifically talking about Javascript, or more specifically languages that do not execute operations "in-order" (async)

Taking this scenario, where the `logger.close()` operation **must run after** the `logger.error()` statement...

```
({
  //SomePromise
})
.then( //Then something else )
.then(function() {logger.close();})
.catch(err =>
  {
    logger.error(err);
    logger.close();
  })
```

With Javascript, **this works fine** with try/finally:

```
.catch(err =>
  {
    try {
      logger.error(err);
    }
    finally {
      logger.close();
    }
  })
```

I'm a total newb to async, promises, etc and how to deal with them (I'm a Python guy).

- Is there a more ideal way to make this work?
- Am I missing an important concept about this or is this method viable and logical?

Comment: Uh, ECMAScript - like most languages, including Python - has a sequential flow, with “async” compatibility/support. And the close function *does* run after the error function shown, except if an exception is thrown.

Comment: The actual/relevant question is probably “How to catch/handle Exceptions with Promises?”

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=promise+catch+exception

Comment: https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc

Comment: Note sure if you know but you can write one-liner lambdas without curly braces. `.then(() => { logger.close(); })` is similar to `.then(() => logger.close())` with the only difference that the first version doesn't return, while the latter version returns the result of the `logger.close()` function call. See: [Arrow function expressions - Function body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thank you!

Comment: `logger` itself is not asynchronous, is it? The only asynchronous thing in your code is the `SomePromise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Promise.prototype.finally()**

The [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) api has a [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

**MDN's example:**

```
p.finally(onFinally);

p.finally(function() {
  // settled (fulfilled or rejected)
});
```

**Applied to your code**

```
({
  //SomePromise
})
.then( //Then something else )
.catch(err => {
    logger.error(err);
})
.finally(() => {
    logger.close();
});
```

Comment: I was trying with a `.finally()` clause but it wasn't working - I'll copy your syntax directly in my next tests and mark this as the answer if it works out! Thanks.

Comment: Yea I just tried it again, for some reason the logger is closing early and I don't get any logs when I put the close() in the `.finally()` block. I don't exactly know why, it "should" work like that.

Comment: @emmdee Is `logger.error(err)` an asynchronous action? In that case you should return the result of `logger.error(err)` assuming it returns a promise to indicate when it's done. The same applies for you `then` callback. If you do asynchronous actions in there, be sure to return the promise each time.

Comment: ^ This is explained at the end of [Using Promises - Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) *"**Important:** Always return results, otherwise callbacks won't catch the result of a previous promise (with arrow functions `() => x` is short for `() => { return x; }).`"* If you call an asynchronous funcion without returning a promise the next `then`/`catch`/`finally` is executed before the function completes.

Comment: The root cause of my issue was the winston-papertrail logger library. Instead of using logger.close() [as the docs stated] I used logger.end() which handled the exit gracefully and the putting it in the `.finally()` block worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of async await ?

```js
const asyncFunc = async () => { something };
const logger.error = async (err) => { something with err }

try {
  var result = await asyncFunc();

} catch (err) {
  await logger.error(err);

} finally {
  logger.close();
}
```

So here you will execute the asyncFunc:

- If everything goes well, the finally block gets executed and the logger.close is called
- If there's an error, the await keyword will wait until that
  logger.error is completed and then move to the finally block which will trigger the logger.close

Comment: This doesn't close the `logger` if there is no error thrown. You should add a [`finally`-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally-block) to this as well. Then move `logger.close()` to that block. It might also be worth noting that the current code can only run inside an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @3limin4t0r thanks for the comment, I updted my answer. I think that should work now